# How can I remove the Translation entries in apt?

Tags: apt, repository

This is the output of `aptitude update`:

```
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security InRelease
Hit http://deb.torproject.org natty InRelease
Get:1 http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg [198 B]
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty InRelease
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security Release
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty Release
Get:2 http://dl.google.com stable Release [1,338 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner amd64 Packages
Hit http://deb.torproject.org natty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty Release
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner TranslationIndex
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates Release
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Sources
Get:3 http://dl.google.com stable/main amd64 Packages [469 B]
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.canonical.com natty/partner Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty Release
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main TranslationIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com natty-updates/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb Release
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://deb.torproject.org natty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/apps TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/apps Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net natty-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Fetched 2,005 B in 45s (44 B/s)
Reading package lists...
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the translation stuff?  I'm tired of it resulting in tons of repository checks rather than it checking far fewer repositories (69 actual repos vs. 169 checks)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

To disable downloading translations, create a file named `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99translations` & put the following in it:

```
Acquire::Languages "none";
```

You may also need to remove existing translation files in /var/lib/apt/lists/

For more information see the man page to apt.conf (5).

Comment: That worked to get most of the items, but entries with TranslationIndex are still showing up.  Any idea how to remove those?

Comment: This looks to be http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=624218 which should be fixed in the version of apt in 11.10

Comment: any backports of it?

Comment: perfect..... those translation things are not showing up in `apt-get update` anymore

Comment: is this for apt_preferences or apt.conf?  it looks like this answer is a bit mixed up.

Comment: @Jayen neither, if you read the first line it says to create a file called `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99translations` then include the code in that file, then apt-get update.  The `apt_preferences` manpage entry holds the data on the syntax though.

Answer (score 11):

Just for the record (since some will trip on this ..) the 99Translations file above will cause apt to barf - remove the "Packages: *" line - just the one line is enough:

```
Acquire::Languages "none";
```

Also, apt will still retrieve the files for your locale/language.

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu 12.x, this is what you want to disable apt from retrieving pkg translations

Comment: Don't forget to issue `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*Translation*` command to remove all existing translation index files after that

Answer (score 5):

Enable pipelining to batch these requests, which is *much* faster:

```
Acquire::http { Pipeline-Depth "200"; }
```

But in my experience it can result in broken downloads; http error codes seem to cascade or something. It should be safe enough if you are talking to apt-cacher-ng (either mirror mode or proxy mode). Otherwise, be prepared to disable it if your mirror breaks.

I would advise against setting languages to `none`, because it breaks `apt-cache search` (none means none, when useful searches would need descriptions in at least one language). The locale-based default includes unnecessary regional variants, but something like this:

```
Acquire::Languages { "fr"; "en"; };
```

is reasonable.

Comment: For me it does not break `apt-cache search` (Ubuntu 13.10).

Comment: Is this still helping in Ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want to download German APT translation files. So, as a comprise I have set explicitly in a new `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99translations` file with order first English then None translations:

```
Acquire::Languages { "en"; "none"; };
```

I have removed all existing German translation files via `rm -v /var/lib/apt/lists/*i18n_Translation-de*`.

Before:

```
root# apt-config dump | grep Languages
Acquire::Languages "";
Acquire::Languages:: "de_DE";
Acquire::Languages:: "de";
Acquire::Languages:: "en";
Acquire::Languages:: "none";
```

After:

```
root# apt-config dump | grep Languages
Acquire::Languages "";
Acquire::Languages:: "en";
Acquire::Languages:: "none";
```

If there are multiple users with different `$LANGUAGE` settings the recommended setting should be (here: with order 1. environment 2. English 3. None):

```
Acquire::Languages { "environment"; "en"; "none"; };
```

AFAICS this is the default setting (see above output of "Before:" section).

[1] http://users.ox.ac.uk/~bioc1289/post/2013/01/right-way-to-not-download-apt-translation.html

Answer (score 0):

Found this as I was searching for a solution too. Was a fresh install of Debian testing. The following command (as suggested above) fixed it:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: Tested on the Natty system. This didnt fix the problem in Natty.  However, since I've upgraded my primary system to Precise, I dont have this issue :P

Answer (score -1):

Go to **Language Support** then click **Install / Remove Languages...** then uncheck the languages that you don't want.

If you removed all languages, it will default to generic English. Note that en-US packages are considered a separate language, so you have to uncheck English to uninstall its packages.

Comment: This only applies in the GUI.  This also doesn't stop the Translations from being gathered by apt-get or aptitude in those older releases.