# How to reduce time in apt-get update?

Tags: apt, time

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.
It seems that it take lot of time for apt-get update.
I can see that it spend lot of time for checking language translations file.
How to disable translations checking while apt-get update?

I want only English.
How to safely remove other language translations?

Comment: You can change the download server in the Software center -> Software Sources -> Download from. Select "other" and then "Select Best Server". This might help a bit.

Comment: This question may have been addressed here: [How can I remove the Translation entries in apt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74653/how-can-i-remove-the-translation-entries-in-apt) and may be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answers to this question:
[**How can I get apt to use a mirror close to me, or choose a faster mirror?**](https://askubuntu.com/q/37753/52923)

I use the recommendation from an answer to that question to add the two lines below to the top of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. This is supposed to encourage the update process to automatically pick a download mirror with better performance. I think it helps.

```
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise main restricted universe multiverse
deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

- **Note:** The lines above are meant to used with the `/etc/apt/sources.list` for 12.04 (Precise Pangolin). For earlier releases replace `precise` with the release's corresponding codename.

  Lucid (10.04), Maverick (10.10), Natty (11.04), Oneiric (11.10)