# Where did packages full descriptions go?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

Several years I notice that Ubuntu is lacking packages full descriptions. F.ex. Debian have this description for 'aptitude':

> Package: aptitude (0.6.8.2-1)
>
> terminal-based package manager
>
> aptitude is a package manager with a number of useful features,
>   including: a mutt-like syntax for matching packages in a flexible
>   manner, dselect-like persistence of user actions, the ability to
>   retrieve and display the Debian changelog of most packages, and a
>   command-line mode similar to that of apt-get.
>
> aptitude is also Y2K-compliant, non-fattening, naturally cleansing,
>   and housebroken.

Ubuntu has this poor description:

```
terminal-based package manager
```

It have happened since 'precise' release. 'trusty', 'utopic' and 'vivid' [are affected too](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). What's wrong with the package description?

Comment: The example description for aptitude looks a LOT better with word-wrap on... the horizontal scrollbar isn't good for that big one line. Please leave it edited with word-wrapping on, or split into smaller lines?

Comment: Looks super now! Was starting to look a little like an "edit war" there ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, the long descriptions were removed from the core Packages files, no doubt to lower their file-size. Localised descriptions are shipped out in separate files and the [main packages list](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/) only has a skimpy version, like:

```
Description: terminal-based package manager
```

But I'm British (en-GB) so when `apt-get update` happens, you can see it downloading translations for both [US English](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en) and [GB English](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/Translation-en_GB):

```
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-proposed/main Translation-en_GB
```

Both of these files have a separate localised version of the long description but the British trumps that colonial gobbledygook, so when I run `apt-cache show aptitude` on 14.04, I see:

```
Description-en_GB: terminal-based package manager
 aptitude is a package manager with a number of useful features, including:
 a mutt-like syntax for matching packages in a flexible manner, dselect-
 like persistence of user actions, the ability to retrieve and display the
 Debian changelog of most packages, and a command-line mode similar to that
 of apt-get.
 .
 aptitude is also Y2K-compliant, non-fattening, naturally cleansing, and
 housebroken.
```

That you're not seeing translations suggests that your language has no translation so it's just using the default one-liner from the main Packages list.

You can see a list of available translations in [the relevant `i18n` directory listing](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/i18n/). Have a look at yours. Confirm the missing translation and then do... *Something*. I'm honestly not sure what the process is for adding a new package translation.

Or as muru suggests, you may have [disabled translations](https://askubuntu.com/q/74653/449). Even if you haven't you could hack that to download `en` translations, even if you aren't English (as long as you can read it!)

Comment: I don't get such a paragraph on Ubuntu 14.04. Only the line from the question is present. Does it depend on what repositories on has enabled?

Comment: Synaptic is great for a more gui-ish package manager, it looks very similar to aptitude too. Would that be ironic that midenok's example package is a solution to his problem?

Comment: Also the package index pages differ too: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/aptitude vs http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/aptitude

Comment: apt-cache show aptitude doesn't show full description to me. As was mentioned, it happened recently: since precise (I use vivid). You can verify this in packages.ubuntu.com.

Comment: That might be it. I disabled [translations](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74653/how-can-i-remove-the-translation-entries-in-apt).

Comment: I've updated. The descriptions are localised.