# "apt-get update" gives many [Ign] errors - is that a problem?

Tags: apt, updates, ppa, repository

I just ran `sudo apt-get update` once again and I thought that there are many lines starting with `Ign` instead of `Hit` in the output.

I wondered what it means and researched on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/294525/367990) and [Super User](https://superuser.com/q/454867/418736), but they had contradictory answers. After discussing with @Seth in chat and some logical thinking, I came to the conclusion that:

- `Hit` means "This package index list is already downloaded and up to date"
- `Ign` means "This index list could not be downloaded, e.g. due to an error 404 (Not found). However, the error can be ignored because only the translations are missing, but the packages are still available in their default language."

**My questions are now:**

- Why do I have so many non-available repositories listed in my configuration? I currently have 23 `Ign`-entries, while 5 of them belong to my installation DVD.
- Do they cause any harm (slow down update process, missing lists, whatever)?
- How can I get rid of them if that is not a bad idea?

**Output of `sudo apt-get update`:**

`Ign` lines only:

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/main Translation-de
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/restricted Translation-de
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com utopic/partner Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-de
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-de
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
```

Full output:

```
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic InRelease
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/main Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/main Translation-de
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign cdrom://Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1) utopic/restricted Translation-de
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic InRelease
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security InRelease
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed InRelease
Hit http://archive.canonical.com utopic Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic Release
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic Release
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security Release.gpg
Hit http://archive.canonical.com utopic/partner Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic Release
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates Release
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/main Sources
Hit http://archive.canonical.com utopic/partner i386 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security Release
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com utopic/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb InRelease
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/main Sources
Ign http://archive.canonical.com utopic/partner Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/main Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/multiverse Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/restricted Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/restricted Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/universe Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com utopic/main Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic/universe Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/restricted Translation-en 
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/main Sources 
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/universe Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/multiverse Sources 
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/restricted i386 Packages 
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/multiverse Sources 
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/universe Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/restricted Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/universe Sources
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/main Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/multiverse Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/restricted Translation-de
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de utopic-proposed/universe Translation-de
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-en
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net utopic-getdeb/apps Translation-de
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release                         
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net utopic/main Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done
```

**Contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:**

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.10 _Utopic Unicorn_ - Release i386 (20141022.1)]/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main restricted #Added by software-properties

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-updates main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic universe
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic multiverse
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-backports main restricted universe multiverse #Added by software-properties

deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-security main restricted
deb-src http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse restricted universe main #Added by software-properties
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-security universe
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu utopic partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu utopic main
deb http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed main restricted multiverse universe
deb-src http://ftp.uni-stuttgart.de/ubuntu/ utopic-proposed main restricted multiverse universe #Added by software-properties
```

**Output of `ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:**

```
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-utopic.list
danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-utopic.list.save
getdeb.list
getdeb.list.save
leolik-ubuntu-leolik-utopic.list
leolik-ubuntu-leolik-utopic.list.save
lestcape-ubuntu-cinnamon-utopic.list
lestcape-ubuntu-cinnamon-utopic.list.save
nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-utopic.list
nilarimogard-ubuntu-webupd8-utopic.list.save
ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-utopic.list
ubuntu-wine-ubuntu-ppa-utopic.list.save
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-utopic.list
yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-utopic.list.save
```

Comment: It would have been nice if the downvoter left a comment explaining his/her personal reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do I have so many non-available repositories listed in my configuration? I currently have 23 Ign-entries, while 5 of them belong to my installation DVD.

Missing translations do not make a repository unavailable. Missing `InRelease` files could, but if the server provides `Release{,.gpg}` files, then it's fine.

> Do they cause any harm (slow down update process, missing lists, whatever)?

Slightly. Apt uses a single connection for multiple requests, so some requests would be delayed, but I don't think it makes much of a difference. As long as the proper `Release{,.gpg}` are also available, the repository will work fine.

> How can I get rid of them if that is not a bad idea?

For translations: [How can I remove the Translation entries in apt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/74653/158442)

For `InRelease`, there will not be any such option. From [this feature request that was closed wont-fix in 2015](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=626026):

> Anyhow, 4 years later we have all accepted the new world order of
>   InRelease and the code actually changed in a way which makes it even
>   harder to avoid at least trying InRelease first, so closing as
>   wontfix.