# apt-get update "Ign" lines for component "inRelease"

Tags: 14.04, apt, apt-mirror

I'm working with a local mirror of the Ubuntu distribution, using the 'apt-mirror' package, and I'm seeing "Ign" lines when I `# apt-get update` from a 14.04 system.

On the system that has the mirror, the mirror list contains the following: (I've not shown the entries for Lucid, Precise, etc.)

```
# Trusty/14.04LTS
deb-i386  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty          main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386  http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty          main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty          main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src   http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates  main restricted universe multiverse
```

The `apt-mirror` command has been run and everything has downloaded for the Trusty mirror list. The system presents this repository mirror via HTTP. On the 14.04 system then, I have a sources list file of:

```
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty main restricted
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty main restricted
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates main restricted
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty universe
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty universe
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates universe
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates universe
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty multiverse
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty multiverse
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-updates multiverse
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security main restricted
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security main restricted
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security universe
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security universe
deb      http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security multiverse
deb-src  http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.dom/ubuntu  trusty-security multiverse
```

When I run an `apt-get update` however, I get serveral "Ign" lines. I understand these are not errors per se, but I would prefer to either "fill in" the mirror to satisfy these, or understand how to make the system stop looking for them if they are not necessary.

```
# apt-get clean
# apt-get update
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates InRelease
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security InRelease
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates Release.gpg
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security Release.gpg
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty Release
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates Release
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security Release
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/main Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/restricted Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/universe Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/main Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/universe Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://ubuntu-mirror.redacted.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Reading package lists... Done
```

Does that mean I'm missing "inRelease" and "Translation-en_US" **components** in my mirror?

My understanding is that there are "main", "restricted", "universe" and "multiverse" **components**... so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

I read in the Debian wiki (somewhere) that "inRelease" (vs "Release") had to do with how packages are signed.

So I'm thinking there's some sort of option that needs to be adjusted on my mirror.

Comment: This is strongly related to my (still unanswered) question here: http://askubuntu.com/q/590848/367990

Comment: yeup, i read that too.