# apt update - prevent multiple "Translation-en" from package side

Tags: apt, package-management, repository

**apt update - prevent multiple "Translation-en" from package side**

I have seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74653/how-can-i-remove-the-translation-entries-in-apt), but that is on the client side - is there no way you can set this in the package - I tried do it in the deb package, but I got the same result.

I can see that other packages is not - I think?

Do you know if it is possible, and if so how to make it not getting all the following extra Translation?

```
sudo apt update
    Ign:1 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ InRelease
    Hit:2 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Release                                                
    Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                
    Ign:4 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Release.gpg                                            
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en                                         
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US                
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en               
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US            
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US
    Hit:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US          
    Hit:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease
    Ign:5 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en             
    Ign:6 https://<user>.github.io/my_ppa ./ Translation-en_US                                               
    Hit:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease                                  
    Hit:7 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt kubernetes-xenial InRelease          
    Hit:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    All packages are up to date.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have created a repository and it all works fine, but after curl the key and the list - when doing apt update the user gets all these "Ign: <nr>".